# Oracle: How to change column data type from VARCHAR to NUMBER without losing data

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl, alter-table

I have the following columns in my table:

- `ID - NUMBER(10,0)`
- `NUMBER - VARCHAR(255)`

All data in the `NUMBER` column are numbers. I would like to change the `VARCHAR` type to Integer Number type. How to do it without data loss?

Comment: Oracle's `NUMBER` type can only support 38 decimal places, so all of your data may not fit without truncation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Oracle does not allow modification of data type of the column if it is not empty so as a workaround, You need to follow the following steps

1. create another column with `NUMBER` data type let's say `"NUMBER1"`.
2. add the data of `"NUMBER"` column into that newly created column(`"NUMBER1"`).
3. Remove the original `"NUMBER"` column
4. Rename the newly created column `"NUMBER1"` to `"NUMBER"`

as following:

**Oracle setup:**

> ```
> SQL> CREATE TABLE YOUR_TABLE (
>   2      ID         NUMBER(10, 0),
>   3      "NUMBER"   VARCHAR(255)
>   4  );
>
> Table created.
>
>
> SQL> DESC YOUR_TABLE;
>  Name                                      Null?    Type
>  ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
>  ID                                                 NUMBER(10)
>  NUMBER                                             VARCHAR2(255)
>
> SQL> INSERT INTO YOUR_TABLE VALUES (1,'1');
>
> 1 row created.
>
> SQL> COMMIT;
>
> Commit complete.
> ```

Showing error if the column data type is changed directly:

> ```
> SQL> ALTER TABLE YOUR_TABLE MODIFY "NUMBER" NUMBER;
> ALTER TABLE YOUR_TABLE MODIFY "NUMBER" NUMBER
>                               *
> ERROR at line 1:
> ORA-01439: column to be modified must be empty to change datatype
> ```

**Solution:**

> ```
> SQL> ALTER TABLE YOUR_TABLE ADD "NUMBER1" NUMBER;
>
> Table altered.
>
> SQL>
> SQL> UPDATE YOUR_TABLE
>   2  SET "NUMBER1" = "NUMBER";
>
> 1 row updated.
>
> SQL>
> SQL> ALTER TABLE YOUR_TABLE DROP COLUMN "NUMBER";
>
> Table altered.
>
> SQL>
> SQL> ALTER TABLE YOUR_TABLE RENAME COLUMN "NUMBER1" TO "NUMBER";
>
> Table altered.
>
> SQL> DESC YOUR_TABLE;
>  Name                                      Null?    Type
>  ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
>  ID                                                 NUMBER(10)
>  NUMBER                                             NUMBER
>
> SQL>
> ```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by executing the following steps.

```
1. Add new column NUMBER1 with type integer.
2. Update table set NUMBER1=TO_NUMBER(NUMBER);
3. Remove column NUMBER.
4. Rename column NUMBER1 to NUMBER.
```

Answer (score 1):

If your table is very large, it would be faster to use [dbms_redefinition](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_redefi.htm#ARPLS042) to do it. Here's an [example](https://www.freelists.org/post/oracle-l/changing-a-column-type,6) of using it.